# Rails 3.1 engine not loading vendor assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a super simple engine for loading some vendored assets: https://github.com/febuiles/strap_on

I include it in my application's `Gemfile` like this: `gem "strap_on"`.

In my `application.css` file I have: `*= require twitter_bootstrap`.

I start the application and I get `couldn't find file 'twitter_bootstrap'`.

I've notice that the path for the engine is not in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`. Any idea of what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your gemspec file - it doesnt look like you include files from the vendor directory, guessing that is your main issue, check asset path after adding and reinstalling - if you look in your gem repository now, i am guessing the files in vendor are not included

Also i would move twitter_bootstrap.js into the twiiter_bootstrap directory and rename it index.js, not sure if this is required or not (you will need to update paths in that file also)

You might also be interested in this post? http://house9.blogspot.com/2011/06/rails-31-asset-gem.html